# cfssl gencert fails on generation from json

Tags: ssl-certificate, devops

[cfssl](https://pkg.cfssl.org/) v 1.2

```
cfssl gencert -initca ca/ca-csr.json
```

where the json is:

```
{
  "hosts": [
    "cluster.local"
  ],
  "key": {
    "algo": "rsa",
    "size": 2048
  },
  "names": [
    {
      "C": "CA",
      "L": "Montreal",
      "O": "My Inc.",
      "OU": "QC",
      "ST": "Montreal"
    }
  ]
}
```

I got a err msg:

> Must specify bundle target through -cert or -domain

From the [example](https://scriptcrunch.com/create-ca-tls-ssl-certificates-keys/) seems I use it the same way.

checking the [code](https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl/blob/master/cli/bundle/bundle.go):

not sure how would it go to that condition.

Q: what actually the way I can use it? to generate the certificate from the JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the incorrect binary.

Most likely you went to the releases section and obtained the first binary (cfssl-bundle_*) for your platform and renamed/aliased it to cfssl.

That is not the one that the linked tutorial uses.

Further down in the list of release artifacts you'll find a `cfssl_<version>_<platform>` binary which is the utility you want.